# Spark DataFrame Lazy Evaluation when select function is called

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Knowing that Spark only do the real job when an action is called (e.g. a show on a DataFrame) I have one doubt regarding the extension of this lazyness behavior.

Imagine the following scenario of a development of a DataFrame with 3 columns:

```
val df = otherDF
.withColumn("aaa", lit("AAA"))
.withColumn("bbb", lit("BBB")
.withColumn("ccc", lit("CCC")
```

After this, I will select only one column and show (trigger an action):

```
df
.select("aaa")
.show
```

**Will spark only compute the "aaa" column and ignore the other ones if they are not needed? Or will it evaluate and process the "bbb" and "ccc" columns also and the select function will only filter the output subset?**

The real scenario here is that I want to create a "master" DataFrame with many columns and complex transformations, but then some sub-processes will select the master DataFrame with only a subset of the columns and add if needed some more specific columns.
I want to guarantee that if a sub-process that only needs 10% of the columns will not be affected by the all evaluation and process of the complete master DataFrame (if this is possible).

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the real scenario, are you only talking about columns computed or also columns from data read in HDFS or some other datasources?

Comment: I'd say that generally yes only the necessary things are retrieved/computed. This is called push-down. You can find articles explaining more in details. I'm not sure for your use case though. Might be better to look at the execution plan afterwards to be sure.

Comment: So, the "otherDF" that I have in the example will be a common dataFrame that will be read from S3/Hive. Then some columns will be created, based on the "otherDF" columns, but in the end the subprocesses will only choose a subset of the complete columns.

Hope I explained properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prepared this sample code:

```
val input = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/*@gmail.com/city_temperature.csv")
val df = input
.withColumn("aaa", lit("AAA"))
.withColumn("bbb", lit("BBB"))
.withColumn("ccc", lit("CCC"))
.withColumn("generated_value",monotonically_increasing_id)
            
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.debug._
df.select("aaa", "generated_value").debugCodegen()
```

I am reading csv, then adding some column and at the end selecting only few of them. I added monotonically_increasing_id to include also column which is not a literal value but is generated dynamically

.debigCodegen() shows us what code was generated, so lets take a look at first version where i am selecting also the generated_value

```
/* 029 */   private void project_doConsume_0(InternalRow inputadapter_row_0) throws java.io.IOException {
/* 030 */     final long project_value_1 = partitionMask + project_count_0;
/* 031 */     project_count_0++;
/* 032 */
/* 033 */     project_mutableStateArray_0[0].reset();
/* 034 */
/* 035 */     project_mutableStateArray_0[0].write(0, ((UTF8String) references[0] /* literal */));
/* 036 */
/* 037 */     project_mutableStateArray_0[0].write(1, project_value_1);
/* 038 */     append((project_mutableStateArray_0[0].getRow()));
/* 039 */
/* 040 */   }
```

Here you can see that code need to calculate id was generated and later executed, its  this part:

> final long project_value_1 = partitionMask + project_count_0;

Now the same code but lets remove second column from select. First lines of code are the same as in previous example

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.debug._
df.select("aaa").debugCodegen()
```

Project_doConsume is different

```
/* 024 */   private void project_doConsume_0(InternalRow inputadapter_row_0) throws java.io.IOException {
/* 025 */     project_mutableStateArray_0[0].reset();
/* 026 */
/* 027 */     project_mutableStateArray_0[0].write(0, ((UTF8String) references[0] /* literal */));
/* 028 */     append((project_mutableStateArray_0[0].getRow()));
/* 029 */
/* 030 */   }
```

Code needed for monotnically_increasing was not generated which means that Spark is able to pushdown projection and generate only columns that are needed